# Attribute or Method?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I am writing a python script which calculates various quantities based on two parameters, the long radius and short radius of a spheroid. It occurred to me that I could write a spheroid class to do this. However, I'm new to object oriented design and wonder if you more experienced chaps can help me.

An instance is instantiated with parameters a and b for the long radius and short radius respectively, so I've designed the class as follows:

```
class Spheroid:
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.longax  = a
    self.shortax = b
```

One of the quantities I want to calculate is the volume. The volume of a spheroid is 4*pi/3 * a * b * b.

My question is, do I define a method or an attribute for this in my class?

e.g. I could define a method:

```
def Volume(self):
  return 4*pi/3 * self.longax * self.shortax * self.shortax
```

or I could just use an attribute:

```
self.volume = 4*pi/3 * self.longax * self.shortax * self.shortax
```

I could also just include it in the init method:

```
class Spheroid:
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.longax  = a
    self.shortax = b
    self.volume = 4*pi/3 * a * b * b.
```

Which is better to use and why? In general, when would I use a method and when would I use an attribute? I wouldn't normally care but I have a whole load of these to implement and I'd like to have an idea about OO design for future reference.

Thanks

EDIT:

After implementing properties as per Martijn's suggestion, I ended up with something like this:

```
class Spheroid(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.shortax = a
    self.longax  = b
    self.alpha=self.longax/self.shortax

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return (4*np.pi/3) * self.shortax * self.shortax * self.longax

    @property
    def epsilon(self):
        return np.sqrt(1-self.alpha**(-2))

    @property
    def geometricaspect(self):
        return 0.5 + np.arcsin(self.epsilon)*0.5*self.alpha/self.epsilon

    @property
    def surfacearea(self):
        return 4*np.pi*self.shortax**2*self.geometricaspect
```

I instantiated an instance s = Spheroid() but whenever I try something like s.volume or s.epsilon I get an AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'Spheroid' object has no attribute 'volume'

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, in my **init** method I used self.alpha = self.longax/self.shortax instead of a/b, does this make any difference? Is one way preferable?

Comment: Excellent question. Note this the tradeoffs are language dependent. One answer might be obvious in C++ with a different answer in Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a 3rd option: make it both an attribute and a method, by using a [property](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Spheroid(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.long  = a
        self.short = b

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return 4 * pi / 3 * self.long * self.short * self.short
```

You access `.volume` like an attribute:

```
>>> s = Spheroid(2, 3)
>>> s.volume
75.39822368615503
```

In order for the `property` descriptor to work correctly, in Python 2 you need to make sure your class inherits from `object`; in Python 3 the baseclass can be safely omitted.

In this case, the calculation of the volume is cheap enough, but a property lets you *postpone* having to calculate the volume until you actually need it.

The above example creates a read-only property; only a getter is defined:

```
>>> s.volume = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You could easily cache the result of the property calculation:

```
class Spheroid(object):
    _volume = None

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.long  = a
        self.short = b

    @property
    def volume(self):
        if self._volume is None:
            self._volume = 4 * pi / 3 * self.long * self.short * self.short
        return self._volume
```

so that you only have to calculate it *once* per `Spheroid` instance.

What you use depends on many factors; how easy does your API need to be to use, how often will the volume be calculated, how *many* Spheroid instances will be created, etc. If you create a million of these in a loop but only ever need the volume for a handfull of them, it makes sense to use a property instead of setting the volume in the `__init__`.

If, however, your class could *adjust* itself based on the volume; say, by adjusting one of the radii automatically, then a `@property` makes more sense still:

```
class Spheroid(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.long  = a
        self.short = b

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return 4 * pi / 3 * self.long * self.short * self.short

    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, newvolume):
        # adjust the short radius
        self.short = sqrt(newvolume / (4 * pi / 3 * self.long))
```

*Now* you have a spheroid which naturally adjusts it's short attribute as you adjust the volume:

```
>>> s = Spheroid(2, 1)
>>> s.volume
8.377580409572781
>>> s.volume = 75.39822368615503
>>> s.long, s.short
(2, 3.0)
```

Note: technically, *anything* you access on an object with `.name` notation is an attribute; methods included. For the purpose of this answer, I used your `attribute` as any value that is not called (doesn't use `()` after the name).

Comment: You might want to mention that another benefit of this is that `volume` is "read-only" as well.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: That is the next step; it is not a requirement :-)

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your post. 

Can you explain why defining a property is better than just using a method? With a method, I would also delay the calculation of the volume until I call the method, no?

Comment: @user1654183: It's a stylistic choice. The attribute hides the fact that it is a calculation, and you cannot give it arguments (you'd always need a method if arguments are needed).

Comment: @user1654183: Other than that, since a property is really a method, there is no difference. If you had a need for a getter *and* a setter (so `.get_volume()` and `set_volume()` where the latter adjusts either `self.short` or `self.long` to make the spheroid fit, for example), then a property really shines.

Comment: Being able to change long and short based on the volume would actually be really helpful. I need to read a bit more into this property business first though. Thank you!

Comment: I will accept it shortly - I'm getting an AttributeError whenever I try something like s.volume, please see my edit. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1654183: An attribute error *in* the property will be masked as an attribute error *for* the property. It's `self.shortax`, etc.

Comment: @user1654183 I consider the expression _"make it both an attribute and a method"_ to be incorrect. Firstly, because _attribute_ is a generic word that covers all kinds of the namespace's members of an object:   _"By the way, I use the word attribute for any name following a dot"_ [help](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and _"There are two kinds of valid attribute names, data attributes and methods"_ [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)

Comment: @eyquem: I quite agree; added a short piece at the end to qualify the terminology.

Comment: @user1654183 Secondly because Martjin means in fact _"make it both a data attribute and a method"_ but it is still incorrect like that because a property attribute is in reality a method, from the point of view of the implementation, not a data attribute. The attribute flavor a property has is only lying in the manner it is called: using the attribute notation. So one must not make confusion between an attribute notation and the  attribute nature of an object. IMO

Comment: @user1654183 However I upvote this answer because it explains well why making ``volume`` a property of the object is better: calculation is done only when needed, and more important for me: the values of shortaxe, longaxe and volume are always kept consistent

Answer (score 2):

will you always use this data?

if not, you could use a property and then lazily compute it...

```
class Spheroid(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.longax  = a
    self.shortax = b
    self._volume = None

  @property
  def volume(self):
      if self._volume is None :
           self._volume = 4*pi/3 * self.longax * self.shortax * self.shortax
      return self._volume
```

Comment: If you change `self._volume = ...` to `self.volume = ...`, then you avoid subsequent function calls.

Comment: @Robᵩ In Python2.7, which I use, it raises an AttributeError.  [ and I've wished so often that I could do that ]

Comment: @Robᵩ: No, you cannot. Data descriptors (like a property) are first looked up on the class and cannot be replaced by a instance attribute.

Comment: You are both correct, I was wrong. I tested with old-style classes, which test wasn't valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement volume as a method because of the following:

1. it can be computed from other attributes, so it saves space to compute it (unless this is very complicated computation and than you can consider caching it)
2. it is not a natural "feature" of the object, for example for circle the radius is an attribute but not the area (this is not really format definition)
3. Something like volume is kind of abstract method, if you want to have family of objects and compute the volume for each of them in polymorphic way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "saves space" argument?

Comment: if you save it as field, you have an extra integer per object